# Plot a subset of variables over different grids

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data:

```
library(dplyr)

samp %>%
head(5)
# A tibble: 929 x 3
    time  city sales
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     1   248
 2     0     2   187
 3     0     3   459
 4     0     5  1422
 5     0     7   196
 6     0     8   397
```

I want to plot the sales of each city against time in a line plot. Overall there are 31 cities. If I plot them, it´s a little confusing.

```
library(ggplot)

samp %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = sales, color = factor(city))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

My goal is to plot 6 cities in each plot and then arrange the plots over 6 grids (31/6). There is the possibility to use facet_wrap.  However, here only one city is in each grid. How can I insert 6 cities in each grid? So only 6 grids with 6 cities remain?

```
samp %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = time, y = sales, color = factor(city))) +
      facet_wrap(.~city) +
      geom_line()
```

[image]

```
structure(list(time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), city = c(1, 2, 3, 
5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
25, 26, 29, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 29, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 
26, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 29, 30, 31), sales = c(248, 
187, 459, 1422, 196, 397, 438, 636, 616, 729, 648, 7291, 488, 
520, 370, 417, 826, 726, 895, 426, 797, 839, 589, 452, 135, 221, 
496, 187, 1594, 269, 453, 466, 664, 656, 784, 683, 8023, 545, 
580, 424, 459, 855, 679, 975, 422, 694, 899, 528, 472, 237, 272, 
563, 362, 2078, 320, 561, 565, 814, 829, 1095, 878, 10403, 705, 
755, 630, 501, 1193, 884, 1416, 533, 1071, 1353, 729, 2269, 583, 
168, 180, 63, 252, 1137, 201, 466, 299, 523, 564, 616, 611, 7259, 
483, 489, 371, 355, 753, 526, 918, 445, 683, 746, 485, 1703, 
408)), row.names = c(NA, -101L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "time", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:23, 24:48, 49:74, 75:100), group_sizes = c(24L, 25L, 26L, 
26L), biggest_group_size = 26L, labels = structure(list(time = 0:3), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame", vars = "time", drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Could you try replacing your `facet_wrap()` call with the following `facet_wrap(. ~ cut_number(city, 6))` and see if that helps?

Comment: I would cut by sales not city so the top sales are grouped together. That doesn't solve the problem of too many colors. I don't see anyway around breaking it up into multiple charts if you want people to be able to identify the city by color.

Answer (score 0):

Given your problem that you want to plot a subset of variables over different grids to improve readability I would follow the suggestions from the two commenters above and combine their approach.

First create groups of cities splitted by sales numbers (sales_group)
Then add another random group (city_group) to reduce the number of cities per grid.
Then print via

`facet_grid(sales_group ~ city_group, scales = "free_y")`.

In a further step you could think about working on the coloring/naming of the cities, but I assume you can take it from here.

Good luck.

```
samp %>%
    group_by(city) %>%
    mutate(sales_max = max(sales),
           sales_group = case_when(
               sales_max < 550 ~ "sales low",
               sales_max > 550 & sales_max < 750 ~ "sales medium",
               sales_max > 750 & sales_max < 1100 ~ "sales high",
               sales_max > 1100 ~ "sales very high"
           )) %>% 
    ungroup()  %>% 
    group_by(sales_group)  %>% 
    mutate(city_group = cut_number(city, 2, label = c("group 1", "group 2"))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = time, y = sales, color = factor(city))) +
    facet_grid(sales_group ~ city_group, scales = "free_y") +
    geom_line()
```